# Error in Python multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I used multi-threading to do a calculation:

```
def calc_score(score, i, j, a, b):
    score[i, j] = func(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')
    db = pd.read_csv('db2.csv', converters= {'create_date': pd.to_datetime})

    m = len(df)
    n = len(db)
    pool = Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    score = np.zeros([m, n])
    for i in range(m):
        a = df.loc[i, 'val']
        if a == 'None' or a == '':
            score[i, :] = 0
        else:
            for j in range(n):
                b = db.loc[j, 'val']
                pool.apply_async(calc_score, (score, i, j, a, b))#multi-threading
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\main.py", line 107, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 356, in apply_async
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 620, in __init__
RuntimeError: can't allocate lock
```

What is the reason and how to solve it?

Can I use mutex to lock the section?

UPDATED:

```
mutex = threading.Lock() 
def calc_score(score, i, j, a, b):
    with mutex:
        score[i, j] = func(a, b)
```

Comment: A full stacktrace would be helpful. Also, does it happen when `func` is a no-op, returning a constant?

Comment: `func` is a function that returns a number between 0 and 1 and every time the return value is generally different.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem is in an attempt to directly share a numpy matrix.

I see these options.

- Make a separate matrix fragment per task, and then stitch them.
- Use explicit memory sharing, e.g. via `multprocessing.Array`, but with numpy it must use some additional tricks.
- If access patterns don't partition neatly, use an in-memory key-value database (redis, unqlite, maybe even sqlite) and store results as (coords tuple, value) from within the processes.

Comment: Can I use a mutex to solve the problem as shown in the updated code?

Comment: I frankly don't know; glancing at the `pool.py` source, I could not even find where the locking might fail.